# Http Verbs (Put, Delete, Post, Get ...) - use them not in an API

Tags: php, http, symfony, model-view-controller

I've got a question on using Http Verbs methods outside of an API/Webservice.

I've read a lot about these verbs, they normally are used in Rest API's. But what if i am writing a "normal" application, a normal website with php based on a mvc framework, is it better to use these http verbs there for the Controller methods too, or should i always use POST ?

Can this "Http Verbs pattern" be used in normal applications, or only when you write an API that should be used/called by others?

Regards.

Comment: You can use as you want, the method (verbs) can be found in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`
If you don't see how to use it, just use POST and GET as usual

Comment: Hi Aurélien, i think i understood how to use them and what each of them is supposed to do. So if i do, it would be a better approach to use them, because it's a well thought standard, isn't it ? Like when i have an entity and i'm having a controller for crud operations for this entity, then i should annotate the controller methods with the right http verb ? (In the mvc framework im using, it's done via annotations on each controller method). Using these verbs is not restricted for building apis then..?

Comment: no restriction, you do what you want :)

Comment: Most browsers only support GET/POST within html.  As long as you are using javascript then your client will be okay.  Just be sure you understand the caching ramifications.

Comment: lol what a strange question, these are http request-methods. theres no request without a method. you most likely will only use GET and if you submit data you can use POST

Comment: IMO this is not a real question for stackoverflow because doesn't show any issue to resolve.

Comment: the question was if it is recommended to also use DELETE, PUT, PATCH, HEAD etc. beside an api. . i would say strange answers of you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many browsers support only GET and POST (and mostly PUT) methods you should use them.

If you will use more specific methods then you can meet some bugs from users who have some exotic homebrew browsers (mostly for mobiles).